# Pinterest API Rate limits while in development

Tags: pinterest, rate-limiting

Pinterest documentation states that an unapproved app receives a sliding 10 requests per hour limitation. It appears that this limitation is per app, not per endpoint or token, which is creating some difficulty for our testers. Can this rate limit be increased by submitting the app for review, or must the app complete the review process in its entirety?

Comment: After you successfully submit an app for approval, each app (with a unique app ID) is allowed 1000 calls per hour for each unique user token.

In both cases, the 60-minute window is a sliding window based on when you make your first request. If you hit your rate limit, you’ll have to wait a minimum of 1 hour to get a few more requests.

Comment: To clarify, we have submitted the app for approval and still have a rate limit of 10. I'm assuming when you say "successfully submit an app" that is after pinterest has approved it, not simply hitting the submit for approval button.